# Work and efficiency puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

There are $2$ people $A$ and $B$. $A$ requires $a\;$ days to complete certain amount of work and $B$ requires $b\;$ days to complete the same amount of work. If $A$ begins the work a day before $B$ begins, then in which of the following conditions will the work get completed quicker than in the case where $B$ begins a day before $A?$

$1.\;n$ is a positive integer and $n(1/a+1/b)=1$

$2.\;b>a$

In my analysis I found that only condition $2$ is necessary to get the work done quicker, but the answer given is only $1$ is necessary. Can someone please explain why $2$ is not sufficient to prove the case?

Comment: Suppose $a=2,b=3$. Then if $A$ starts earlier he completes half the work the first day and they finish on the second day.. If $B$ starts earlier, he completes a third of the work on the first day and they finish on the second day. Do you count that as finishing earlier in the first case?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that fractional days will be taken into account in assessing the difference.

Your answer is the  correct one.

*ADDED:*

If "certain amount of work" and "same amount of work" mean the *full* work, all that condition $1$ means is that working together, $A$ and $B$ complete the  full work in $n$ days, and if instead they mean some *fraction* (may be improper fraction) of the full work, they complete that fraction of the work in $n$ days.

Either way, it has no bearing on the question asked.